# Updating created problems with Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

this is my very first post, Big Deal to me, appreciate your help Colleagues.

I recently updated Android Studio, (this is why I don't like updating) it forced me to create a new gradle file it called Hello ESE.gradle (ESE being the Company's name), the file simple contains this :

group = "itet"
version = "1"

the updating placed this file in the res/values directory when I built, this caused an error saying the file needed to end in .xml,

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

  > /Users/lokeke/AndroidStudioProjects/CalorieCountdownAppforAndroidBrown/app/src/main/res/values/Hello ESE.gradle: Error: The file name must end with .xml

I thought a gradle does not belong in the values directory so I removed it and put in the build directory but now the errors are even worse, I moved this Hello ESE.gradle to other places where gradle could look for it but still nothing works it won't build, don't know what to do now (how I wish I could go back to pre-update!!!)

Comment: UPDATE : I decided to move to Andriod Studio 4.0 to see if this would fix the problem, it partially did but now I have a new set of errors, "error: resource string/app_name (aka ese.com.caloriecountdownappforandroidbrown:string/app_name) not found." it gives me this for all my strings that where previously found, I need help in finding a solution to fix this, what is going wrong??

Answer (score 0):

I just simply updated all the tools I was using, Gradle, SDK, the works, and transferred to the Hello gradle file to the gradle.properties directory, this seems to have fixed it.